# Creating a transparent gap between header and page content

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm using Wordpress and the twentythirteen theme. What I'm trying to achieve is to create a 30px gap between the header and the page content. 
Here's a webpage that has what I'm talking about: http://wp-themes.com/elisium/

When I add marging or padding, it only adds some white space instead of showing the background picture. I tried some reverse engineering, on the site mentioned above and it seems that the gap is created by `<div class="clearbig">`. I looked up its CSS code but it isn't of much help:

```
.clearbig {
    clear:both;
    height:10px;
}
```

To avoid copying huge portions of code here, I set up a website for testing purpose:

http://mywptestsite.is-great.org

So how do you create this gap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to delete `background-color: #fff` from .site class and add it (`background-color: #fff`) to .site-main class

Answer (score 1):

it's because you wrapped all of your content in `#page` which has a white background. What you need to do is take your header out of that `div` and then you can create that space you want. You'll have to do soemthing like this:

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
    //stuff in here
</header>
<div id="page" class="hfeed site">
    //rest of your content
</div>
```

Also you'll have to set a width on your `header` since it wouldn't be held inside that container. That way setting the `auto` on the left and right margins will center your content.